# select all visible objects?

Tags: mesh, objects, selection-tools

I have a model of a vehicle that contains a ton of objects. seats, seat belts, etc down to individual screws and such.  All I want is the "skin" really but not sure how to do it.  Is there a way to quick select all visible objects ignoring what i cannot see?

Thank you for your time/help!

Comment: you could select everything visible with the lasso tool (ctrl), then inverse the selection with ctrl i, then delete.

Comment: The lasso tool for me seems to select everything inside and out.  So the inverse turns out to be nothing.

Comment: you don't give enough precision, are you in 2.8? in Edit mode? if you're in Edit mode, then enable the Limit Selection to Visible option

Comment: in 2.79 lol.  what luck.  i'll see if my version does the same.  thanks much for the info

Comment: well, actually what I say works with 2.79, so it should work

Comment: credit to you, moon.  that worked out for me.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Select everything visible with the lasso tool ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd> ), then inverse the selection with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd> to delete.